# MVC best practices and view controller offloading?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

In order to offload my view controller I decided to separate TableViewDataSource and TableViewDelegate from my view controller into their own classes. I'm confused with how I can solve these following problems:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    hideNavbar = true
    let vc = TopicSelectionViewController()
    self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: { 
        self.hideNavbar = false
    })

}
```

1. If I put this in TableViewDelegate's own class, what is the best
   practice of referencing to the navigaitonController?
2. What is the proper way of referencing to the tableView that is using
   this dataSource/delegate?
3. Can I have Networking layer in dataSource?

If so, how to notify the view controller that is displaying the table view to update it's view after the data is retrieved from the server?

Comment: If you are trying to follow MVVM pattern, where you separate data from ViewController, you will still have to put these delegate function in your ViewController, not the other class, you just manipulate the dataSource array in the other class

Answer (score 0):

1. Referencing to the navigationController? You don't need to reference to the navigationController. Any view controller gets it's default navigationController.
2. There is no proper way for referencing to the tableView. You can use any of them that suits your need as all of them are directed from **Apple**. You can either set it's dataSource / delegate through your code or from the ***connections inspector*** (or, you can use *control-clicking + dragging* mechanism).
3. `UITableViewDataSource` is intended to be working with table view’s appearance. (See here for more: [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) and [UITableVIewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate)). That is you configure how your table view should look like. It has nothing to do with your actual data. But you can configure your networking layer to update your `TableView` when your data is retrieved from the server. You just *reload* your table view when you are ready to show your updated data.